# Accessing value from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

how can i get or access the value in nsdictionary, i just want to get the valuetext from a chiller

```
data (
        (
                {
            Caption = Chiller;
            MetricClass = 10;
            Value = "109.4000015258789";
            ValueText = "109.4";
        },
                {
            Caption = "Chiller Product";
            MetricClass = 10;
            Value = "37.40000152587891";
            ValueText = "37.4";
        },
                {
            Caption = Freezer;
            MetricClass = 10;
            Value = 104;
            ValueText = "104.0";
        },
                {
            Caption = "Freezer Product";
            MetricClass = 10;
            Value = "42.79999923706055";
            ValueText = "42.8";
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            Caption = Chiller;
            MetricClass = 10;
            Value = "109.4000015258789";
            ValueText = "109.4";
        },
                {
            Caption = "Chiller Product";
            MetricClass = 10;
            Value = "48.20000076293945";
            ValueText = "48.2";
        },
                {
            Caption = Freezer;
            MetricClass = 10;
            Value = 104;
            ValueText = "104.0";
        },
                {
            Caption = "Freezer Product";
            MetricClass = 10;
            Value = "53.59999847412109";
            ValueText = "53.6";
        }
    ),
```

Comment: Woa... format that better. Check the FAQ for how to do that.

Comment: sorry i am newbie here. :)

Comment: No problem; takes a bit to learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like valid (JSON) data... but if it was simply an NSArray of NSDictionaries, then this should work:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in data)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", dict[@"Caption"]);
}
```

Comment: Why nobody, that's why I said "doesn't look like valid (JSON) data".

Comment: Doesn't look like a hippopotamus either.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is an NSArray that contains NSArrays that contain NSDictionaries.  (In NSLog dumps the arrays are bracketed by `()` while the dictionaries are bracketed by `{}`.)

You need to "peel the onion" -- use `objectAtIndex` to access an array entry, `objectAtIndex` again to access the inner array's entry, then `objectForKey` to get the values from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hot states your have an array of arrays of dictionaries and one can easily use the new literal syntax.

Example:

```
test: NSArray * data = @[
                   @[
                       @{
                           @"Caption" : @"Chiller",
                           @"MetricClass" : @10,
                           @"Value"  : @"109.4000015258789",
                           @"ValueText" : @"109.4",
                           },
                       @{
                           @"Caption" : @"Chiller Product",
                           @"MetricClass" : @10,
                           @"Value"  : @"37.40000152587891",
                           @"ValueText" : @"37.4",
                           },
                       @{
                           @"Caption" : @"Freezer",
                           @"MetricClass" : @10,
                           @"Value" : @104,
                           @"ValueText" : @"104.0",
                           },
                       @{
                           @"Caption" : @"Freezer Product",
                           @"MetricClass" : @10,
                           @"Value"  : @"42.79999923706055",
                           @"ValueText" : @"42.8",
                           }
                       ],
                   @[
                       @{
                           @"Caption" : @"Chiller",
                           @"MetricClass" : @10,
                           @"Value"  : @"109.4000015258789",
                           @"ValueText" : @"109.4",
                           },
                       @{
                           @"Caption" : @"Chiller Product",
                           @"MetricClass" : @10,
                           @"Value"  : @"48.20000076293945",
                           @"ValueText" : @"48.2",
                           },
                       @{
                           @"Caption" : @"Freezer",
                           @"MetricClass" : @10,
                           @"Value" : @104,
                           @"ValueText" : @"104.0",
                           },
                       @{
                           @"Caption" : @"Freezer Product",
                           @"MetricClass" : @10,
                           @"Value"  : @"53.59999847412109",
                           @"ValueText" : @"53.6",
                           }
                       ]
                   ];
NSLog(@"Value: %@", data[0][0][@"Value"]);
NSLog(@"Value: %@", [[[data objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Value"]);
```

> Value: 109.4000015258789
>   Value: 109.4000015258789

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for the time and replies, from the response i figured out what i need to do.

```
 for (NSArray *test in [dictobject valueForKey:@"ValueText"]) {

                [arrayobject addObject:[test objectAtIndex:2]];
            }
```

thanks again.

Comment: not actually done :( how can i just get thee ValueText of a Caption is equal to cooler.

Comment: i cannot use the objectAtindex since the result is not fixed to number of elements. :( please help